# Tornado vs eventmachine

Tags: python, ruby, tornado, eventmachine

To get good performance in ruby eventmachine you need to apply rules like:

- don't block reactor
- using em drivers to everything that system uses

Does similar rules apply to Python's Tornado library?

Comment: Of course. They are the same, actually. :) Don't block the reactor and use evented libs.

Comment: what Sergio said, as well as the main reason why EM can be hard for early learners is that the rcore and stand ruby libs aren't evented (unlike nodejs, which was built to be evented from the outset)